# how to earn avg of one row in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a store procedure in sql that give me average of some column:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Financial] 

AS
BEGIN
    select avg([aa ]) as 'aaa',
    avg([bb]) as 'bbb',
    avg([cc ]) as 'ccc',
    avg([dd]) as 'ddd',
    avg([ee]) as 'eee',
    avg([ ff]) as 'fff'
from [FIN]
END
```

Now my problem is if I wanna give avg for the result of this procedure,what can I do?you know the result of this procedure is one row,now I want to earn the avg of this row. what should I add to my current procedre?

Comment: How should the average be calculated? You want an average of averages or you want all of the values to be averaged? (can be different results if there are nulls)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery:

```
select ([aaa]+[bbb]+[ccc]+[ddd]+[eee]+[fff])/6 as avg from
(select avg([aa ]) as 'aaa',
    avg([bb]) as 'bbb',
    avg([cc ]) as 'ccc',
    avg([dd]) as 'ddd',
    avg([ee]) as 'eee',
    avg([ ff]) as 'fff'
from [FIN]) sub;
```